# How to handle v-for with input and large data?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I recently facing a problem when using `v-for` to iterate large data which has `input` component. The problem is when i text something into the input field, it take so long to respond (almost 2 second on 1000+ data). here is my v-for

```
<v-col>
        <v-row v-for="item in editedItem.priceList" :key="item.id" no-gutters cols="12">
          <v-col cols="7" class="mr-3">
            <v-text-field v-model.lazy="item.type" solo :rules="[rules.required]" label="Jenis Barang" />
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols="2" class="mr-3">
            <v-autocomplete
              v-model.lazy="item.unit"
              :items="unit"
              label="Satuan"
              solo
            />
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols="2">
            <v-text-field v-model.lazy="item.price" solo :rules="[rules.required]" type="number" label="Harga Satuan" prefix="Rp " />
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-col>
```

How can i improve the performance of this code? because i know it will rerender all the component everytime value in input changed.

Comment: Is that why because you use `v-model.lazy` !!

Comment: yes, just tryin out someone suggestion but no luck